# AppForge vb6 and wm61

Tags: mobile, vb6

Anyone here have any experience with AppForge MobileVB used with Visual Basic 6 and Windows Mobile 6.1.  I am trying to get a fuser to work but dont understand the syntax.  This framework has been out of business for years.  I inherited this application, and will soon move to .net but for now its in this mess.

Please tell me someone has some idea,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed with AppForge targeting PalmOs and Windows Mobile. It was 7 years ago but my app still runs in 10.000 devices.
What is your problem? what are trying to do?
Finally, last released AppForge was v6.5.3 that needs licencse per device. Afortunately developers comunity where able to crack it. If you don't have this version, I can send it to you.

Comment: yes please send it to me.  But also, I have a mobile app that did some standard serial port printing (esc/p epson) i believe.  This function works until this current handheld now it wont print. Makes not sense.

Comment: Also, how does one go about making a .net assembly work with appforge code? (how do I create a fuser in .net that the appforge project can use)

Comment: I would be interesting in getting some help from you in a serious way.

Comment: If you read this again, HeavyVice, please let me know if your interested in assisting me.